# Cómo indexa MongoDB un documento que no tiene el campo usado en el índice?

Tags: mongodb, indices

Una de las propiedades de MongoDB es se "schema-less" que quiere decir que puedo tener un documento como

```
{nombre : 'diego'}
```

en la misma colección donde hay otro documento como

```
{nombre : 'diego2', edad : '35'}
```

Entiendo, que los índices en MongoDB [están implementados usando un *b-tree*](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes-introduction/) al igual que en otras bases de datos, en el que los nodos del árbol apuntan a documentos de la colección. Usando los índices una *query* no necesita hacer un *full table scan* de la colección al hacer una operación tipo *find* o *sort* que pueda usar un determinado índice.

Mi pregunta es, qué pasa con documentos del a colección que no tengan un campo que se use la el índice? Por ejemplo, qué pasa si intento indexar por "edad" en una colección que tiene los dos documentos que he puesto arriba?

El documento que no tiene el campo se "pierde" para el árbol de índices? Me dice `db.coleccion.createIndex({'edad' : 1})` que no puedo crear el índice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues depende de la forma en la que crees el índice. Si lo creas de esta forma:

```
> db.coleccion.insert({"nombre": "cesar"})
> db.coleccion.insert({"nombre": "diego", "edad": "35"})
> db.coleccion.createIndex({"edad" : 1})
```

Las documentos que no contengan el campo también serán indexados lo cual puede tener un impacto en el desempeño.

Si quieres indexar un campo que no va a estar presente en todas los documentos de la colección entonces lo mejor sería usar [Sparse Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/#sparse-index-incomplete-results). Pero ten en cuenta el siguiente comportamiento:

> If a sparse index would result in an incomplete result set for queries and sort operations, MongoDB will not use that index unless a hint() explicitly specifies the index.

Lo cual quiere decir que si el resultado de un query está incompleto al usar el índice, MongoDB no lo usará a menos que lo indiques explícitamente usando [`cursor.hint()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/).

Por ejemplo:

```
> db.coleccion.insert({"nombre": "cesar"})
> db.coleccion.insert({"nombre": "diego", "edad": "35"})
> db.coleccion.createIndex({"edad" : 1}, {sparse: true})
> db.coleccion.find().sort({"edad": -1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e8401b010d418cf416c326"), "nombre" : "diego", "edad" : "35" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e84016010d418cf416c325"), "nombre" : "cesar" }
> db.coleccion.find().sort({"edad": -1}).hint({"edad": 1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e8401b010d418cf416c326"), "nombre" : "diego", "edad" : "35" }
```

Al usar `{sparse: true}` en la creación del índice, te aseguras de indexar solo aquellos documentos que tienen el campo indexado.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo. Encontré una respuesta a lo que buscaba. Seguiré dejando la tuya como la respuesta aceptada porque es muy completa, pero he querido añadir una propia para explicar qué ocurre en la estructura que implementa los índices, que es lo que me intrigaba.

Answer (score 2):

En MongoDB los campos que no existen en un documento se evalúan a `null`, y también existe una entrada para ellos (para el valor `null`) en el B-Tree que implementa ese índice).

Por ejemplo, si insertamos en una colección los objetos

```
{x : 3}
{x : 55}
{x : 6}
{x : null}
{x : "hola"}
{a : 1} -- no tiene campo "x"
{b : 1} -- no tiene campo "x" tampoco
```

y hacemos `db.coleccion.createIndex({ x : 1})`, al hacer luego un `db.coleccion.find().sort({x : 1})` obtendremos los documentos (omito _ids por claridad y comodidad) en el orden.

```
{x : null}
{a : 1}
{b : 1}
{x : 3}
{x : 6}
{x : 55}
{x : "hello"}
```

De nuevo,

> si un documento no tiene un campo este se evalúa a `null`, y este valor también tiene una entrada en el árbol que implementa el índice para este campo.

Es decir, que aunque un documento no tenga un campo, un valor para dicho campo se evalúa al crear un índice sobre él.

Incluso si llevamos las cosas un poco más lejos, si creamos un índice en la colección con la opción {unique : true} no podremos tener más de un documento en la colección que no tenga el campo incluido en el índice, ya que el índice no admite valores duplicados para el campo y dos documentos que no tuviesen dicho campo (evaluado a `null`) estarían repitiendo el valor null para el campo (a menos claro que usásemos la opción *sparse* y entonces sólo los docs con ese campo se indexarían y podríamos tener más de un documento que no tuviese el campo pese a tener un índice *unique*).

Comment: Muy buena información, +1